# Listing OSX GIS tools

Tags: software-recommendations, osx

Most Open Source tools are cross platform.  However, some GIS tools such as ArcGIS are platform specific (Windows only).

What are some of the GIS tools that are usable on the mac?

I am hoping to get more obscure libraries, packages, and programs that I didn't know about on OSX similar to [dotspatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/) and [sharpmap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) for windows

Answer (score 12):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure. It should
> be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the type of
> question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange site, but
> if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free to do so
> by editing this answer.

---

go to [kingchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/) and you have all the FOSS4G desktop GIS compiled for Mac:

- GRASS GIS runs on MacOSX: http://grass.osgeo.org/download/software.php#g64x

As of 2015, the new stable major release GRASS GIS 7.0.0 is available. The graphical user interface based on wxPython (introduced in GRASS GIS 6.4) has been enriched with many new features in order to make complex GIS operations available as simple as possible. The old Tcl/Tk based GUI has been dropped. The developers have added important new functionality to the core system, among that the ​new Python interface to the C library. This new API permits users to create new GRASS GIS-Python modules in a simple way while yet obtaining powerful and fast modules. Furthermore, the vector library was significantly improved to make it faster and more efficient, along with support of ​huge files. This requires an ​easy to manage topology format update including a new spatial index. A lot of effort has been invested to standardize parameter and flag names. Finally, there are a series of new modules to analyse raster and vector data; some of the already existing modules were improved and made faster (some even 1000 x faster).

For details see https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/7.0.0-News

- QGIS will run on OSX. You can download it from
  http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Download#MacOS_X

- PostgreSQL, PostGIS, GDAL and others (Mapserver)

You have also  OpenJump, GvSIG, Udig, Ossim and Cartographica (not free, 495 $)

- R and R spatial packages
- Merkatoor (OpenStreetMap editor)
- some other things

Mono works on Mac, so DotSpatial must work. GISLook & GISMeta are Mac-Specific. They are plugins for Mac OS X that show GIS data in the Finder.
Supported formats: ESRI Shape, E00, ArcInfo Coverage, USGS DEM, SRTM, ESRI ASCII grid, ESRI Binary grid, BIL, BIP, BSQ, Surfer Grid, PGM.

there are some such as:

- [MicroImages TNTMips](http://www.microimages.com/products/tntmips.htm),
- [Cartographica](http://www.macgis.com/),
- [MapDiva](http://www.mapdiva.com/).

Also, ArcGIS is usable in a VM as long as you're not doing anything too 3D intensive.  Presumably, that would be true of other proprietary GIS applications.

Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools - GAT for Spatial Analysis is JAVA program and probable run on OSX even as VISAT/BEAM for RS.
And MultiSpec run well on the MAC for Image Classification (despite being freeware).